# Need a regex command to find a value in an xml file

Tags: regex, splunk

I have a large xml file that is within a logging statement.  I am using Splunk to extract values from the xml file.  I have to use regex to find these values because I cannot change the config files. I requested the change but it is pending...
This is an example of the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tmsTrip xmlns="http://ground.fedex.com/schemas/linehaul/trip" xmlns:ns2="http://ground.fedex.com/schemas/linehaul/TMSCommon">
   <tripNumber>129271010</tripNumber>
   <tripLegNumber>1</tripLegNumber>
   <origin>
      <ns2:numberCode>5902</ns2:numberCode>
  ...many more fields....
   </origin>
   <destination>
      <ns2:numberCode>5087</ns2:numberCode>
   ...many more fields....
   </destination>
  ...many more fields....
   <purchasedCost>
      <purchasedCostTripSegment>
         <purchCostReference>2644025</purchCostReference>
         <carrier>BNSF</carrier>
         <vendorType>RAIL</vendorType>
         <carrierTrailerType>53PC</carrierTrailerType>
         <origin>
            <ns2:numberCode>4022</ns2:numberCode>
...many more fields....
         </origin>
         <destination>
            <ns2:numberCode>4040</ns2:numberCode>
...many more fields....     
         <stopOff>
            <ns2:stopOffLocation>
               <ns2:numberCode>9996</ns2:numberCode>
...many more fields....       
            </ns2:stopOffLocation>
         </stopOff>
         <schedDispatchDate>2020-05-27T05:00:00.000Z</schedDispatchDate>
...many more fields....
      </purchasedCostTripSegment>
      <purchasedCostTripSegment>
         <purchCostReference>2644025</purchCostReference>
         <carrier>NS</carrier>
         <vendorType>RAIL</vendorType>
         <carrierTrailerType>53PC</carrierTrailerType>
         <origin>
            <ns2:numberCode>4061</ns2:numberCode>
...many more fields....
         </origin>
         <destination>
            <ns2:numberCode>4040</ns2:numberCode>
...many more fields....         
         </destination>
         <stopOff>
            <ns2:stopOffLocation>
               <ns2:numberCode>4040</ns2:numberCode>
 ...many more fields....      
            </ns2:stopOffLocation>
         </stopOff>
         <schedDispatchDate>2020-05-27T05:00:00.000Z</schedDispatchDate>
 ...many more fields....     
      </purchasedCostTripSegment>
   </purchasedCost>
</tmsTrip>
```

I need to identify the **ns2:numberCode** for the origin and destination for each of the **purchasedCostTripSegment**.

I am doing this in Splunk so the regex might be particular to Splunk.
I am able to get find the origins and destinations if I use the function **mvindex()** and count the instance of the **ns2:numberCode**.  But then they are individual fields and do not display clearly in a table.
This is the regex command that will return the first origin of a PurchaseCostTripSegment:

```
| rex max_match=0 "\<ns2\:numberCode\>(?P<location>[^\<]+)" | eval Segment1_Origin =  mvindex(location, 7)
```

I need a regex that will return all of the origins of the PurchaseCostTripSegments
I tried this:

```
| rex max_match=0 "\<purchasedCostTripSegment\>*\<origin\>*\<ns2\:numberCode\>(?P<Origin>[^\<]+)"
```

It returned no value.
How can I write the regex to find all of the ns2:numberCode values that are in this section of the xml:

```
     <purchasedCostTripSegment>
             <purchCostReference>2644025</purchCostReference>
             <carrier>BNSF</carrier>
             <vendorType>RAIL</vendorType>
             <carrierTrailerType>53PC</carrierTrailerType>
             <origin>
                <ns2:numberCode>4022</ns2:numberCode>
</purchasedCostTripSegment>
      <purchasedCostTripSegment>
         <purchCostReference>2644025</purchCostReference>
         <carrier>NS</carrier>
         <vendorType>RAIL</vendorType>
         <carrierTrailerType>53PC</carrierTrailerType>
         <origin>
            <ns2:numberCode>4061</ns2:numberCode>
</purchasedCostTripSegment>
```

In the above instance, I want to return values, 4022 and 4061,

Comment: It would be but as I mentioned above the configuration file needs to be changed and I cannot access it.  I requested the change but I need this data ASAP.

Comment: Try `|  rex max_match=0 "<purchasedCostTripSegment>[\s\S]*?<origin>\s*<ns2:numberCode>(?P<Origin>\d+)"`

Comment: THANK YOU SOOOO MUCH!!!!! That worked! Please add this as an answer so I can check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this as a temporary workaround:

```
| rex max_match=0 "<purchasedCostTripSegment>[\s\S]*?<origin>\s*<ns2:numberCode>(?P<Origin>\d+)"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/h4ldo0/1).

**Details**

- `<purchasedCostTripSegment>` - some literal text
- `[\s\S]*?` - zero or more chars, as few as possible
- `<origin>` - some text
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespace chars
- `<ns2:numberCode>`  - some text
- `(?P<Origin>\d+)` - Named capturing group (for Splunk, it must be a named group):  1 or more digits.